# Driver r8169 not working after installing kernel 3.9.8

Tags: networking, kernel, realtek

I tried to install kernel 3.9.8 on my Kubuntu raring, but the network driver don't work anymore! (r8169) I hope that it is fixed as soon as possible.

I went to [kernel.org](http://www.kernel.org) and there is written that I can ask for support here.
So if there are other users with my same problem or users that know how to resolve this problem help me please.

Thanks.

Comment: I have just installed mainline 3.10 kernel on ubuntu 13.04 and it seems to be fixed.

Comment: The kernel.org website certainly does not mention that you should ask help from here. In fact, mainline kernels are unsupported by Canonical. Please see https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/MainlineBuilds#Kernel.2BAC8-FAQ.2BAC8-DebuggingMainlineBuildsSupport.Does_the_kernel_team_support_the_mainline_kernel_builds.3F for more details.

Comment: @papukaija Considering that [we help people run third-party software](http://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic) like MATLAB on Ubuntu, it would be strange if we didn't help people run mainline kernels on Ubuntu. As I believe [this related meta question and the votes on its answers indicate](http://meta.askubuntu.com/q/6098/22949), we help people who run modified Ubuntu systems, so long as they are not in effect instead asking about some other *full OS* that has its own separate support structure (like Mint). I recommend seeking some community consensus before assuming this should be closed.

Comment: Sorry, I just read the Wiki page. Thanks for the link.